# How to render all instances with an id from another model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a model :folder that belongs to :user and takes a user_id. A user can create as many folders as they want, and the homepage renders all folders that have the user_id of the current user. However, using this code on the homepage:

```
<ol class="folders-vertical">
  <%= render @folders %>
</ol>
```

with this instance variable in the homepage controller:

```
@folders = current_user.folders
```

It also renders the :folder model itself. So, each user's first folder is the :folder model instead of the actual first folder they create. How can I avoid rendering this?

Comment: Do you think you can rephrase this? It makes absolutely no sense with the code you have provided. Please edit. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use something like this:

```
@folders = Folder.where(user_id: current_user.id).drop(1)
```